# Multiple independent NIC - slow network print (printer discovery?)

Tags: networking, printing, network-printer

I have a network printer (Samsung) connected to WiFi router, printing from notebook (Win7) connected to the same router using WiFi worked well; DHCP - network 192.168.8.0/24, gateway 192.168.8.1, printer on standard TCP/IP port - 192.168.8.50.

I connected the wired NIC to some specialized device (USG) - static IP, network 192.168.2.1/24, no gateway, USG IP 192.168.2.2 - direct connection. Each print is delayed by approx. 30 seconds (no matter of document size). I tried to disable the wired adapter, printing started immediately.

PINGing printer address shows no delays, even with wired NIC connected. Tracert routed through wireless NIC.

Is there any "search for printer" phase, which can be skipped / skipped for selected interface?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Is your "specialized device (USG)" a network printer? Is it the same network printer you were using before?

Comment: No, it is a medical ultrasound device, laptop and USG are communicating by using TCP/IP connection (DICOM). It should have no impact on printing. Still using the same Samsung printer, connected to the same WiFi router, but printing slows down.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly. The laptop is connected to a WiFi network, on which the network printer is accessible. But when you plug in the Ethernet cable to the USG, and try to print from the laptop to the same network printer over WiFi, it takes 30 seconds before printing starts. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.